# C# calling Delphi DLL function with class pointer paramater

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

I've some issue in calling a Delphi DLL function from C# that contain a pointer parameter to a class.

Could someone help me to understand where I'm wrong?

Delphi function is defined as

```
function CallQPLExt(ADeviceCode: PChar; AProva : string; var AData:  TQPLData): boolean; stdcall;
```

Where TQPLData is:

```
TQPLData    = Pointer;
```

Then I have defined:

```
PProva = ^TProva;
TProva = class;
```

Where TProva is

```
TProva = class
  private
  public
    Pippo : PChar;
end;
```

And inside CallQPLExt function I did

```
function CallQPLExt(ADeviceCode: PChar; AProva : string; var AData:  TQPLData): boolean;
var
  HostCode : String;
begin
  HostCode:= PProva(AData)^.Pippo; //  CurrentTest^.Host_Code;
```

The issue is that PProva(AData)^.Pippo gives an access violation and in debug I could see that Pippo is "Inaccessibile value"

In C# code I have

```
[DllImport(@"D:\AMS\3.03\EXE\LAB_QPLMGR.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention =     CallingConvention.StdCall)]  
public static extern bool CallQPLExt(string deviceCode, string prova, ref Prova qplData);
```

Where Prova type is

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct Prova
{
public string Pippo;  
}
```

And the funcion is called in this way

```
Prova resultat = new();

resultat.Pippo = "Pippo";

boolOk = CallQPLExt("ABI", "prova", ref resultat);
```

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes here. Do you control both the Delphi and the C# code?

Comment: Yes, but Delphi code could not be changed :-(

Comment: Then you have a problem. Because the string parameter can't be passed. It's not interop safe. Why can't you change the Delphi code given that it is unfit for purpose.

Comment: Why is the Delphi code taking a **`var` reference** to a pointer? Does it modify the pointer to change what it points at? If not, then the `var` doesn't belong. In any case, the C# `Prova` class and the Delphi `TProva` class are not interop-compatible with each other. Not that it matters, because the Delphi code is not dereferencing the passed pointer correctly anyway to access the class object (even if the code was interop-safe), as the `PProva` type doesn't belong, either. This code needs a major redesign, but you are likely SOL since you say the "Delphi code could not be changed".

Comment: Yes, you are correct, dll method change the content of the structure pointed by the pointer parameter.